# Select from multiple Database | Oracle | Perl | DBI

Tags: database, oracle, perl, select

I need to do a select on a number in Database A.Table A and also check if this Number exists in Database B.Table A

So far I have tried

```
select ID from Table A where ID in (select ID from UN/PW@//host:1521/SID.Table A)
```

I have no idea if this is the correct syntax.
I am currently writing this in Oracle Developer and then adding it to my perl code using DBI and DBD Oracle.

Help appreciated thanks.

Comment: do you have dblinks setup in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `CREATE DATABASE LINK`

Answer (score 0):

Open two separates DB connection which will point you to two different databases, then use first connection to obtain value from database A and second connection from database B, at the end compare what you got in PERL. In order to be able to query two different databases in a one query you need to use db link. Check this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_distdbs.htm#BABJDEED